# How do I make a wordpress theme full width?

Tags: css, wordpress, width

I tried my best but I couldn't make the following theme full width/screen by editing the CSS. I'd be very much grateful if you could show me or give me a hint regarding this customization.

http://demo.mythemeshop.com/sociallyviral/

You see the footer in the above theme(It's full width), how do I make the whole theme's body/container full width like the footer?

Note: I tried adding/removing margins/paddings etc.

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish something like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYosU.jpg you will need to do the following changes in your css file:

```
.main-container {width:100%;max-width:100%}
#page, .container {width:100%}
```

Answer (score 0):

do the following change in responsive.css file

```
.main-container {
    /** max-width: 96% replace this with bellow  */
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

remove these styles from style.css file

```
.main-container{
    width: 1170px;
}
.container{
    max-width: 1170px;
}
.primary-navigation {
    max-width: 1170px;
}
```

Then your site will work full-width

Answer (score 0):

Replace the following styles and that will do it

Style.css line 305

```
.primary-navigation {
display: block;
float: left;
width: 100%;
text-align: left;
}
```

Style.css line 174

```
#page, .container {
max-width: 100%;
min-width: 240px;
}
```

Responsive.css line 63

```
.main-container {
max-width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to click on **Appearance** `>>` **Customize** `>>` **Additional CSS.**

```
.container {
    width: 70%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using GeneratePress theme and Elemetor page builder and had same problem on mobile-view.
here, elementor-page is section where all content goes.

I used this code:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
    .elementor-page{
    overflow-x:hidden;
}}
```

Comment: The proper way to ask a question like this would be to create your own Ask Question, and if you think it will be helpful provide a link back to this 2015 question as being similar or related.