# How Do I Make My Wordpress Theme Full Width?

Tags: wordpress

and thank you in advance to anyone who responds! I would like to know how to make my Wordpress theme "full width."

http://www.PaidMFTInternships.com

I would love to have the option of expanding the width so that my content can cover more of the page. I saw there was another thread that asked the same question ([How do I make a wordpress theme full width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29051679/how-do-i-make-a-wordpress-theme-full-width)); however, I'm afraid I need a little more direction with regard to my particular theme (Chosen). Thank you so, so much for any support you can offer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your page content is inside

```
<div class="center">
```

and in you css

```
.center {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 85%;
}
```

Change or override the width: 85% to 100%

UPDATE:
The page I'm seeing right now has:

```
<div class="overflow-container" id="overflow-container">
    ...
    <div class="max-width" id="max-width">
        ...
        <div class="post-content">
            ...
            <div class="fl-module-content fl-node-content">
```

with CSS:

```
.overflow-container {
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0 4.167%;
    position: relative;
}

.max-width {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1400px;
}

.singular .post-content, .singular .post-meta, .error-404 .post-content, .error-404 .post-meta {
    padding: 0 18.1681%;
}

.singular .post-content, .singular .post-meta, .error-404 .post-content, .error-404 .post-meta {
    padding: 0 13.6261%;
}

.singular .post-header, .singular .post-content, .singular .post-meta, .error-404 .post-header, .error-404 .post-content, .error-404 .post-meta {
    padding: 0 9.08406%;
}

.fl-module-content {
    margin: 20px;
}
```

You can do most of what you want by adjusting `.max-width{max-width}`, `.post-content{padding}` and `.overflow-container{padding}`.  Maybe change `.fl-module-content{margin}` to 10px (for mobile anyway)

Comment: I don't see that code anywhere in the CSS... I briefly experimented with a new theme about an hour ago and then changed it back, so you may not have been looking at the theme that I've been using and need help with. Could you please take another look? Sorry!

Comment: I updated my answer to adjust the theme installed as I write this.

Comment: You're welcome.  If that did the trick then perhaps you could accept this answer.

Comment: Done (and happy to do so)! I couldn't find the .fl-module-content in the CSS file... but the desktop version looks exactly the way I envisioned it now! And mobile looks fine as long as it's viewed in landscape mode.

Comment: You could add a few media queries to adjust for mobile portrait orientation.