# Make WP "Edge" theme full width

Tags: html, css, wordpress, themes

I have the exact same question as [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29051679/how-do-i-make-a-wordpress-theme-full-width) had, except it's a different theme. :) I'm trying to make [this page](http://www.acornacrespuppies.com/golden-doodle-puppy-photo/) (and others like it) full-width instead of blog style with an invisible sidebar. I tried messing with

```
.container { max-width:
```

but I'm not getting what I was hoping for. I only know the very basics of CSS, so I'm not really up to figuring out how it goes. Can someone give me a hint please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the content on your page is also in another container called `#primary` that has `width: 70%` applied to it, you could add this to make that content 100% width:

```
#primary {
  width: 70%; // Remove this.
  width: 100%; // Add this.
}
```

[image]

---

If you remove `max-width` from `.container`, the [sample page](http://www.acornacrespuppies.com/golden-doodle-puppy-photo/) you provided defaults to 100% width.

```
.container {
  max-width: 1170px; // Remove this line entirely.
}
```

[image: Full Width]

Comment: If you only wanted the content of your pages at 100%, use the `#primary` CSS code I gave you. If you are trying to make both the content and container full width, use both CSS changes.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think that's exactly what I needed.